# Find and print out occurrences of a specific character in a String (shell/AIX)

Tags: shell, sed, grep, aix

I have the following problem.In a shell script, I need to find out the position of multiple dots ('.') in a String.

I found some solutions, but the problem is, they work on a Linux shell but not on an AIX shell.

Example:
The String looks something like this:
`someString-10.12.16.somestring.sql`
(Yes, it's a filename)

I tried it with grep:
`echo $string | grep -aob '\.' | sed -n '2p' | cut -c 1-2)`
but grep under AIX doesn't support the option -ob

I tried it with sed: `sed 's/\([^\.]*\..*\)\..*/\1/' | wc -c`
but there, i get the error message:`sed: Function s/\([^\.]*\..*\)\..*/\1/ cannot be parsed`

Can anyone give me a solution that runs in an AIX shell?
For each dot, one command that returns the position of that dot.

Thank You :-)

Comment: What exactly is your expected result? The example you posted only returns the second occurence. Do you need a list of all occurences? I'm not sure what you mean by "For each dot, one command that returns the position of that dot".

Comment: No, i don't need a list of occurences. I need a command that gives me the position as a number to a specific dot/period.

I found a solution now: `echo "someString.0.4.text" | tr . '\n' | sed -n '2p' | wc -c`
But the wc -c command prints some spaces before the return value, why is that?

I will cut them out and print my complete solution later.

Answer (score 0):

you can try these;

to returns the position of first dot: (the indexing start with 1 not 0;)

```
 echo `expr match "someString-10.12.16.somestring.sql " '[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.'`
```

the second dot;

```
echo `expr match "someString-10.12.16.somestring.sql " '[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.'`
```

the third dot;

```
echo `expr match "someString-10.12.16.somestring.sql" '[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.'`
```

the last dot;

```
echo `expr match "someString-10.12.16.somestring.sql" '[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.'`
```

Eg;

```
user@host:>echo `expr match "someString-10.12.16.somestring.sql" '[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.'` &&
> echo `expr match "someString-10.12.16.somestring.sql" '[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.'` &&
> echo `expr match "someString-10.12.16.somestring.sql" '[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.'` &&
> echo `expr match "someString-10.12.16.somestring.sql" '[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.[a-z:A-Z:0-9:-]*.'`

14
17
20
31


user@host:>echo `expr match "123.567.90." '[0-9]*.'`
4
user@host:>echo `expr match "123.567.90." '[0-9]*.[0-9]*.'`
8
user@host:>echo `expr match "123.567.90." '[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.'`
11
```